# Changes done to object from member function does not persist. Scope/ reference issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, scope, reference

I will try to keep this short and neat. I have two files, Main.js and Component1.js. I am trying to implement the module pattern but i am having troubles with getting changes to persist after being made in an event handler. I will explain the code as i go along, i am writing this in nodejs and this is the short version of each file:

Main.js

```
var component1 = require("Component1");
var components = { compA: component1(), compB: {} };
```

Component1.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    var count = 0;

    function listener(e) {     // Event handler of custom event.
        console.log(count);
        count++;
    }

    return { count: count }
}
```

Now, if i add the following line to Main.js

```
components.compA.randomString = "Hello";
```

and change listener() in Component1.js to

```
function listener(e) {     // Event handler of custom event.
    console.log(typeof randomString);
    console.log(count);
    count++;
}
```

i get the following print-out after issuing 1 custom event tied to the listener:

```
undefined
0
```

If i were to issue a second custom event the print-out would read:

```
undefined
1
```

but if i were to now console.log the compA.count in Main.js i would see that it was still zero.

I am guessing that this means that the listener either has access to a different scope, and therefore neither change "persisted" from the perspective of the other (count === 0 for Main.js, string undefined for the listener), or that compA and the listener referes to two different objects? I am arriving at this conclusion because if i now change Component1.js to

```
module.exports = function () {
    var count = 0;
    var _this;

    function listener(e) {     // Event handler of custom event.
        console.log(typeof _this.randomString);
        console.log(_this.count);
        _this.count++;
    }

    function init() {
        _this = this;
    }

    return { count : count, init: init }
}
```

and add the following line to the end of Main.js:

```
components.compA.init();
```

and issue 2 new custom events i get the following print-out:

```
string
0
string
1
```

and the correct count would persist to components.compA.count.

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Facts:

First let's start with some facts about [data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

1. **Fact #1:** Primitive values (numbers, strings, boolean, ...) are copied when assigned:

```js
var a = 5;
var b = a;

b++;

console.log(a);  // a is still 5
console.log(b);  // b is 6
```

2. **Fact #2:** Non-primitive values are not copied, but only a reference to them is passed around:

```js
var a = { prop: 5 };
var b = a;

b.prop++;

console.log(a);    // a is changed to ...
console.log(b);    // ... b's value, because both a and b are pointing to the same object so changing one will alter the other.
```

### Why doesn't the first code work?

**1.** Case of `randomString`:

In the first code, you are adding the `randomString` property to the object returned at this line:

```
return { count: count }
```

which clearly won't magically create a new variable called `randomString` to be available to use inside the function in *Component1.js*. If you have stored that object into a variable called `myObject` for example, you could have accessed it using `myObject.randomString`.

**2.** Case of `count`:

You're accessing the `count` property of the aforementioned object, which is a copy of `count` variable, since the value is a primitive value (**Fact #1**), changing one won't affect the other. Thus when you update the variable `count` inside `listener`, the property `count` of the object (which is assigned to `components.compA` in *Main.js*) won't get updated.

### The fix:

Just get rid of the standalone variables and use an object (to benefit from **Fact #2**):

```
module.exports = function () {
    var myObject = { count: 0 };                       // use an object

    function listener(e) {
        console.log(myObject.randomString);            // when randomString get assigned on the other side (Main.js) this will be defined
        console.log(myObject.count);                   // use myObject.count not count
        myObject.count++;                              // ... same here
    }

    return myObject;                                   // return the object, according to Fact #2, any changes to this object (either on this side or the other) will be reflected, ie both this side and the other point to the same object
}
```

Now, when you do:

```
var components = { compA: component1(), compB: {} };
```

in *Main.js*, both `myObject` and `components.compA` will point to the same object, thus any changes made by one will be reflected on the other. If you add a `randomString` property to `components.compA`, you can access it from *Component1.js* via `myObject.randomString`. When you increment `count` in *Component1.js*, `components.compA.count` is also incremented, because, in fact, both are the same thing.

### Why does the second code work?

Well, because you're kind of doing the same as the fix code above. Your `init` function just assignes its `this` value to the variable `_this`. Since `init` is called on "THE OBJECT" (our returned object), the value of `this` is that object. So basically it's the same as the above fix code, but you needed a whole new function just to assign the object to a variable, which is **redundant**.

Comment: I hope this makes sense :-)